# Dealing with layers that sometimes load and sometimes do not via ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have a map with 3 layers: 2 featureLayers and one ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer.

sometimes it loads perfectly, sometimes(50% or 60% of the time) it doesn't.

When the layers do not load, a very cryptic message appears:

```
Error: Unable to complete operation.
...,"https:"));k=h.content;var x=h.url,y=s&&h.form,F=D; v=t.isDefined(v)?v:F.useCors...
```

At first I believed this error is caused by network latency. That is, sometimes the network is too slow and when the js map performs some operation, the data hasn't arrived yet and the error is thrown, however, i've noticed that when data does not load a call to /ArcGIS/rest/info?f=json fails.

What will be the best way to handle this situation?

Code:

```
require(["esri/map", "esri/geometry/Extent", "esri/layers/FeatureLayer", "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer"], 
function(Map, Extent, FeatureLayer, ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer) {             
    var bounds = new Extent({
        "xmin" : -79.50,
        "ymin" : -4.60,
        "xmax" : -66.50,
        "ymax" : 12.8,
        "spatialReference" : {
            "wkid" : 4686
        }
    });

    var theMap = new Map(idDiv, {
        extent : bounds,
        slider : false,
        logo : false,
        showAttribution : false
    }); 


    //window.setTimeout(function() { 
        var urlFeatureServer = "xxx/FeatureServer";

        var fl = new FeatureLayer(urlFeatureServer+"/0", { 
            id: "fl1",
            mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_SNAPSHOT, 
            outFields:["*"] 
        });

        var  myId = xxxx;
        fl.setDefinitionExpression("OBJECTID=" + myId);         

        theMap.addLayer(fl);
    //}, 1500);

    theMap.addLayer(new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("xxx/MapServer", {id: "myBaseLayer"}));


    fl = new FeatureLayer(urlFeatureServer+"/1", { 
        id: "fl2",
        mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_SNAPSHOT, 
        outFields:["*"] 
    });
    fl.setDefinitionExpression("id_xxx =" + myId);                  

    theMap.addLayer(fl);            
});
```

Comment: Is it the same layer every time? Where (and what type) of datasource is it coming from? Personally I **hate** diagnosing network problems, at best you're only responsible for half the potentials for failure. Is it possible the layer is being locked? If it fails to load can the page be refreshed and the layer then reloads, conversely if it loads properly does it drop out later?

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Hello Michael, i've updated the question and now it contains the js code. Layers come from two different servers. When the problem appears, after a variable number of reloads it works.  Sometimes it only takes one reload, sometimes 20 or 30. Haven't noticed a pattern yet. And, if you got it working, there is no guarantee that the next time you press f5 things will run smoothly.